# How to read a particular element from array which is the part of object in handlebar file from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, express, mongoose

Below is my mongo db json file.
I want to read the 'topic' element from array 'Addtasks' for each its object element in .hbs(handle bar) file when the route /addTask is called in express.

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5f2313cb1351d606046660fd"),
"email" : "mike@g.com",
"name" : "Mike Tyson",
"Addtasks" : [ 
    {

        "otherdetails" : "haha great!",
        "website" : "asad.com",
        "keywords" : "article importance, article generation, article quality",
        "words" : 1000,
        "topic" : "How article is generated?",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f2314011351d606046660ff")
    }, 
    {

        "otherdetails" : "Not much thanks!",
        "website" : "abcdxyz.co.in",
        "keywords" : "niggas are great, yo whatsup!",
        "words" : 2000,
        "topic" : "whats your name nigga?",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f23142d1351d60604666101")
    }
],
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second arg to .find() to project the values you want.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/LLuM1sd5Raq

```
db.collection.find({}, {
  "Addtasks.topic": 1,
  name: 1, // Add whatever other fields you need as well, remove if not
  email: 1,
})
```

Yields:

```
[
  {
    "Addtasks": [
      {
        "topic": "How article is generated?"
      },
      {
        "topic": "whats your name nigga?"
      }
    ],
    "_id": ObjectId("5f2313cb1351d606046660fd"),
    "email": "mike@g.com",
    "name": "Mike Tyson"
  }
]
```

Comment: How could I return it to handle bar means now how to use the result in handlebar file? Since this I will be writing find() code in nodejs side.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in your data something like this::

```
res.render('mytemplate.hbs', { items: jsObject.Addtasks });
```

then your hbs could look like this:

```
  <ul>
      {{#each items}}
          <li>{{this.topic}}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

(Somewhat unrelated, but that json-file is not valid JSON. JSON and javascript objects are not the same thing. )